# I need to Know the use of setting exposure time iso manually from AVCaptureManualExposureBracketedStillImageSettings?

Tags: swift, iphone, avfoundation

What would be the best values to put in for `iso` and `exposureDuration`? Or do I need to get it as per `AVCaptureDevice`?

My purpose here is to get bracketed images with exposure times that gives best HDR Images results.

```
for index in (0...3) {
    if index == 0 {
        exposureSettings.append(AVCaptureManualExposureBracketedStillImageSettings.manualExposureSettings(exposureDuration: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.01, preferredTimescale: 1000), iso: 50))
    } else if index == 1 {
        exposureSettings.append(AVCaptureManualExposureBracketedStillImageSettings.manualExposureSettings(exposureDuration: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.005, preferredTimescale: 1000), iso: 200))
    } else if index == 2 {
        exposureSettings.append(AVCaptureManualExposureBracketedStillImageSettings.manualExposureSettings(exposureDuration: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.20, preferredTimescale: 1000), iso: 500))
    } else if index == 3 {
        exposureSettings.append(AVCaptureManualExposureBracketedStillImageSettings.manualExposureSettings(exposureDuration: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.250, preferredTimescale: 1000), iso: 600))
    }
}
```